# String split with different separators JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, split

I am asking you how to split a string using different separators and when the string is empty return just an empty space.
I don't know to combine both.

All I have is:

```
function split(string) {
  var str = string.split(/[+-*]/);
  return str;
}
```

Example:

```
split("este-es+otro*ejemplo"); // => ["este", "es", "otro", "ejemplo"]
split(''); // => [""]
```

Thank you.

Comment: error messages are there to be read

Comment: Fix that, and your function results in the desired output

Answer (score 1):

Move the `*` at the first position inside square bracket (`[]`).

***If any special character, such as backslash `(*)` is immediately after the left square bracket, it doesn't have its special meaning and is considered to be one of the characters to match literally.***

Try `/[*+-]/g`

```js
function split(string) {
  var str = string.split(/[*+-]/g);
  return str;
}

console.log(split("este-es+otro*ejemplo"));
```